# How can I find My Cart Total With Repeater in OnItemDataBound (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, shopping-cart

I want to find the total price of the items in the shopping cart. But if the product has a discounted price, I have to get discounted price and if there is no discounted price I have to get normal price for total price.

This is my repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RptrShoppingCart" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RptrShoppingCart_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="LblProductPrice" runat="server" Text='<%#int.Parse(Eval("DiscountedPrice").ToString()) > 0 ? Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("DiscountedPrice")) * Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("Piece")) : Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("NormalPrice")) * Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("Piece")) %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:Label ID="LblShoppingCartTotal" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

**Note: I did not intentionally write the repeater filler code**

And my C# code:

```
decimal total = 0;
protected void RptrShoppingCart_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    DataRow dr = function.GetDataRow("SELECT Product.DiscountedPrice FROM ShoppingCart AS SC INNER JOIN Product AS P ON SC.ProductID = P.ID WHERE SC.UserID = '" + Session["UserID"] + "'");

    DataRowView item = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;

    if (Convert.ToDecimal(dr["DiscountedPrice"]) > 0) // This means if it is a discounted price
    {
        total += Convert.ToDecimal(item["DiscountedPrice"]) * Convert.ToDecimal(item["Piece"]);
    }
    else
    {
        total += Convert.ToDecimal(item["NormalPrice"]) * Convert.ToDecimal(item["Piece"]);
    }
    LblShoppingCartTotal.Text = string.Format("{0:C}", total);
}
```

For example: I add a  1 piece product with a normal price: 10$ but a discounted price: 8$ and add a 2 piece product with a normal price: 20$ that does not have a discounted price.

**The sum of the cart should be: (1 x 8$) + (2 x 20$) = 48$** but my cart total looks 8$. Where am i doing wrong?

Comment: Don't do it in the `ItemDataBound` event. Calculate your total from the original data, whatever it is that you're binding to the control.

Answer (score 0):

You did alright you just are setting the label in the wrong part of the page life cycle.

This is one of the last life cycle events so you cant go wrong.

```
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        LblShoppingCartTotal.Text = string.Format("{0:C}", total);
    }
```